# Get name value of event target- AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling

I'm implementing a text display area inside an app that displays selected text when the user mouses over  one of four elements.  Rather than creating a handler function for each element, I would like to get the name of the instance that is calling the handler in order to implement a switch statement. I've tried two ways, but both aren't working:

```
//install event handlers
initialText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
timeText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
withdrawalText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);


//also tried without toString, same result
var name:String= evt.target.name.toString();
var name=String= evt.currentTarget.name.toString();
```

Both of those return undefined for the variable name.  However, in the debugger, I can trace the event values through currentTarget.name, and that shows the instance firing the handler function, whether it be `withdrawalText, initialText or timeText`.  So how can I apply the name value to a variable in order to determine which text block to display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for each (var field:TextField in [initialText, timeText, withdrawlText])
         field.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverEventHandler);

function mouseOverEventHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
switch (evt.currentTarget)
       {
       case initialText:      /*initialText specific code*/       break;
       case timeText:         /*timeText specific code*/          break;
       case withdrawalText:   /*withdrawalText specific code*/
       }
}
```

this is untested, but it should work as long as the scope of your text field instance variables reach the mouseOverHandler.